# Rails: Using service class methods in a scope query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, scope

I have a user model.

I'm trying to set my user index view to show only those users who have completed an onboarding process.

My approach to doing that is:

index:

```
<% Users.onboarded.each do |user| %>
```

In my user.rb, I tried to define a scope, for onboarding, as:

```
  scope :onboarded, -> { where (:user_is_matchable?) }
```

I have a method in my organisation service class which has:

```
class UserOrganisationMapperService

  attr_accessor :user
private

  def user_is_matchable?
    profile.present? && matching_organisation.present?

  end
```

When i try this, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `onboarded' for Users:Module
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Firstly: `Users` or `User` in your `user.rb` file.. what's the actual name of the class?  because it should be `User` not `Users`

Comment: You defined `onboarded` in `user.rb` but you are calling it on `Users` module. You should be calling it on `User` instead.

Comment: Secondly: `scope :onboarded, -> { where (:user_is_matchable?) }` this is just not going to work. a scope is an ActiveRecord query - it can only deal with details of the actual structure in the database. if you don't have a *column* in your users table called `user_is_matchable?` then this scope will complain and not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: `Users` or `User` in your `user.rb` file.. what's the actual name of the class?  because it should be `User` not `Users`

Secondly: `scope :onboarded, -> { where (:user_is_matchable?) }` this is just not going to work. a scope is an ActiveRecord query - it can only deal with details of the actual structure in the database. if you don't have a *column* in your users table called `user_is_matchable?` then this scope will complain and not work.

you need to make that scope into something that would work just on the database.

I'm only guessing (you haven't given us the full structure of your relations here) but would you be able to do something like:

```
scope :onboarded, -> { where ("profile_id IS NOT NULL AND matching_organisation_id IS NOT NULL") }
```

???

Alternatively, you'll need to make it run just in ruby - which will be slower (especially if your table gets very big, as user-tables are wont to do). But if you're ok with it being super slow, then you could do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.onboarded
    all.select(&:user_is_matchable?)
  end
```

or something similar...

Comment: Hi - yes, I could use that idea. I don't have a 'matching organisation id' in my database. I have a method to check whether there is one. Instead, I could use this idea, but I don't know how to write it in code:   scope :onboarded, -> { where ("user.profile_id IS NOT NULL AND user.profile.organisation_id IS NOT NULL") }

Comment: I tried the second suggesting (a method for self.onboarded), but I get this error: undefined method `user_is_matchable?' for #<User:0x007fba13ed08d0>

Comment: @Mel That's because `user_is_matchable?` is a private method, move it above the `private` declaration

Comment: @jamesw - I tried moving it above private, but I get the same error message as when it's below private.

Comment: Thanks both for the suggestions. I found a way to make the first suggestion work.