# Rails 4 - how to write a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, scope

I'm trying to figure out how to write a scope that checks for the presence of associated attributes.

The gist of what I want to try is a scope in my user model:

```
scope :onboarded, -> { where ("user.profile_id IS NOT NULL AND user.profile.organisation_id IS NOT NULL") }
```

I have another model called Profile. The associations are:

```
User has_one profile
Profile belongs to User.
```

The above scope is written in my user model. Its based on a suggestion from this post [Rails: Using service class methods in a scope query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958664/rails-using-service-class-methods-in-a-scope-query)

I'm not sure if I should try making a scope in my profile model to check if there is an id or an organisation id and then somehow trying to test that in my user model, or if I can chain models together in my user scope to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to just use `joins` as this will perform inner joins, since you are actually checking for existing associations and not only simple attributes.

Considering you also have a `belongs_to` relation between `profile` and `organization` you could do this:

```
scope :onboarded, -> { joins(profile: :organization) }
```

This will return all users with a profile, that has an organization.